# Section overlays on another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Dear Stackoverflow community,

I'm very desperated about following setup:
- I have a Website with a Jquery onepagescroll design.
- If the width of the browsers window is below a certain point (769px) the onepagescroll disapears
- Instead a Gumby based design gets activated

But when happening so
   ... the third of the three sections overlays over the second one a
   ... after the first section is a gap

I researchead about four hours on this problem and couldn't solve it. 
I hope you can help me.

Yours Sinceryl,
yooui


**Code:**
index.html (http://pastebin.com/6fMtkBbm)

jquery.onepage-scroll.js (http://pastebin.com/FnQWWe7J)

Comment: Instead of using pastebin, please post a [short and to the point version](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code on here instead. Also, you can paste your code on http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com to provide us with a live demo to test with. Do also paste the code here though.

Comment: My problem is, i don't know where the problem in the code is....so i can't post a short version of it

Comment: At least link to a working demo, instead of just a paste of your code.

Comment: @yooui readup on [ask] and [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the mandatory [How to write the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Comment: Well, responsiveFallbackWidth is set to "768". What else do you expect it to do?

Comment: @Joeytje50 I'm so sorry, totaly forgot the Website [simon-frey.de](http://simon-frey.de)

Comment: @Nix the Fallback works very well, but the sections overlay...and that looks very bad

Comment: hmm, that seems problem with overflowing content.

Comment: Does this have anyhing to do with overflow:auto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the spacing and overlap, take a look at your CSS. The three "section" elements each have a height of 100%, you'll have to change that in your responsive styles.

So try adding something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .onepage-wrapper .section {
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: height: auto; --> you got it :D but there is the the gap between the sections, any opinion on that?

Comment: Adjusting the height to auto should also remove the gap... if not, try adding margin: 0; to the above code.